# can't update column from integer type with parameter in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to update a column of type integer in my table And this is the error message I get : "to data type int"
Can someone please help me?

this is the code of procedure :

```
@table nvarchar(20),
@nameColumnID nvarchar(15),
@id nvarchar(9),
@homeNumber int
```

DECLARE @sql int

```
IF(@homeNumber != 0)
        SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @table + ' SET homeNumber =  ' + @homeNumber + ' WHERE ' + @nameColumnID + ' = ' + @id   

     EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "EXECUTE(@sql)" only instead of "EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql"

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters for the values where you can (i.e. not identifiers):

DECLARE @table nvarchar(20);
DECLARE @nameColumnID nvarchar(15);
DECLARE @id nvarchar(9);
DECLARE @homeNumber int;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

```
IF (@homeNumber <> 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @table + ' SET homeNumber =  @homeNumber WHERE ' + @nameColumnID + ' = @id';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
                       N'@homeNumber int, @id nvarchar(9)',
                       @homeNumber=@homeNumber, @id=@id;
END;
```

You also declared `@sql` to be an integer.  Probably just an oversight.  However, if `homeNumber` is intended to be a phone number, you should use a string.  Phone numbers can start with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the int id to string 
This is a working code for table on my machine.

```
@table nvarchar(20),
@nameColumnID nvarchar(15),
@id nvarchar(9),
@homeNumber int

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(400)

IF(@homeNumber != 0)

        SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @table + ' SET homeNumber =  ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @homeNumber) + ' WHERE ' + @nameColumnID + ' = ' + @id   

     EXECUTE (@sql)
```